# How to restart SOLR search using Solrj from page?

Tags: java, solr, solrj, fedora-commons

I'm iterating whole solr using solrj. Solr will return me page with uuid's records and I'm checking that uuid in my Fedora Commons Repository. I want iterate whole solr, in my case It can take up to one week to finish. So far It ran 3 days a then it failed on error not related to solr.

So I'm asking, is there a way how to run search from some specific page of results? Let's say I would always log my last page, so next time when my program fails, I dont need to run it from beginning, but instead I will run it from last page where my program failed. 
Can anybody help? Thank you.

How I iterate solr:

```
for (String model : models) {
        try {
            //SOLR
            final String solrUrl = "http://localhost:1234/solr/test";
            HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build();
            solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
            SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
            query.setQuery("fedora." + model);
            query.setRows(10);
            query.addSort("PID", SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);
            String cursorMark = CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_START;
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                query.set(CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_PARAM, cursorMark);
                QueryResponse rsp = solr.query(query);
                String nextCursorMark = rsp.getNextCursorMark();
                for (SolrDocument doc : rsp.getResults()) {
                    ....I do something with result
                }
                if (cursorMark.equals(nextCursorMark)) {
                    done = true;
                }
                cursorMark = nextCursorMark;
            }
            solr.close();
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: you can add/store the success page count somewhere may be a file/database etc...After failure you can check what the last count at the time of failure and you can start from there

Answer (score 1):

If the index hasn't changed, the `cursorMark` value is still valid. As long as you keep the last `cursorMark` stored locally, you can restart the pagination by using that cursorMark.

The `cursorMark` indicates how far into the sorted result set you've progressed, so it's just as good as a page number in regular pagination.

If the index has changed however, you can't re-use the same cursorMark and expect to get all results (if you're sorting on a field that can have entries added earlier - something different than time) - but that wouldn't be true for regular pagination either.